# How to view cypress mochawesome reports in jenkins after running test step inside docker container?

Tags: jenkins, cypress, mochawesome

I'm running my cypress tests on Jenkins inside a dockerized container and I generate cypress mocha awesome report, but I don't know how to display it inside Jenkins.

This is my `cypress.json` content

```
{
  "integrationFolder": "test/specs",
  "supportFile": "test/support/index.js",
  "video": true,
  "reporter": "node_modules/cypress-multi-reporters",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "reporterEnabled": "mochawesome",
    "mochawesomeReporterOptions": {
      "reportDir": "results/mocha",
      "overwrite": false,
      "html": false,
      "json": true,
      "timestamp": "mmddyyyy_HHMMss",
      "showSkipped": true,
      "charts": true,
      "quite": true,
      "embeddedScreenshots": true
    }
  },
  "screenshotOnRunFailure": true,
  "screenshotsFolder": "results/mochareports/assets/screenshots",
  "videosFolder": "results/mochareports/assets/videos",
  "baseUrl": "http://testurl.com",
  "viewportWidth": 1920,
  "viewportHeight": 1080,
  "requestTimeout": 10000,
  "responseTimeout": 10000,
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 10000,
  "watchForFileChanges": true,
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

And here is my scripts which I run locally.

```
  "clean:reports": "rm -R -f results && mkdir results && mkdir results/mochareports",
    "pretest": "npm run clean:reports",
    "cypress:interactive": "cypress open",
    "scripts:e2e": "cypress run",
    "combine-reports": "mochawesome-merge results/mocha/*.json > results/mochareports/report.json",
    "generate-report": "marge results/mochareports/report.json -f report -o results/mochareports -- inline",
    "posttest": "npm run combine-reports && npm run generate-report",
    "test:e2e": "npm run pretest && npm run scripts:e2e || npm run posttest",
```

I can view my generated report successfully in the local environment.
Here is my **jenkinsfile** content

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                echo 'Checking out the PR'
                checkout scm
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Destroy Old Build'
                sh 'make destroy'
                echo 'Building'
                sh 'make upbuild_d'
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Running Tests'
                sh 'make test-e2e'
            }
        }

        stage('Destroy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Destroy Build'
                sh 'make destroy'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `make test-e2e` actually runs the `test:e2e` script inside a docker container, the tests actually run and I can see the reports get generated on Jenkins but I don't know how to view it.
[image]

I need to view it in a separate inside Jenkins, also I don't know why I can't access it via `Jenkins workspace`.
btw. I'm adding the results file in `.gitignore`

This is my local report preview
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the HTML publisher plugin for Jenkins for this:

https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher/

Within your Jenkinsfile add a stage to publish the HTML reports

e.g.

```
    publishHTML([
        allowMissing: false,
        alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
        keepAll: true,
        reportDir: 'cypress/cypress/reports/html',
        reportFiles: 'index.html',
        reportName: 'HTML Report', 
        reportTitles: ''])
```

Comment: actually, I'm getting an error generating the report itself as displayed in the test results screenshot in Jenkins. so, I don't know what's the problem exactly. 

also, I'm running the tests inside a docker container, that's why my results folder doesn't appear in the workspace on Jenkins so, how can I pass the `reportDir` to the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I used the HTML Publisher plugin as the mentioned solution above however my problem was that my results file was in the docker container not in Jenkins workspace and I fixed this problem by copying the folder from a docker container to Jenkins workspace.

`docker cp container_name:/app/results ./results`